# How can I use PyMongo insert_one function with a json file but with my own _id?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use PyMongo to insert json files in my database.

That part is quite easy, but I want to give my own "_id" every time I insert something in that database.

I think that could be simple if I always have control of what is in that json file, but I don't have. Actually I am reading information from a web page, turn into json file and then insert in database.

How can I do that?
I already try insert and then find that object and modify _id field, but python gives me this error:

> Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Comment: Since _id is immutable it must be specified as the value you actually want when you insert it.  If you are using Python to read in a file and insert document by document theoretically you could alter the value found in the file for field '_id' to anything you like before calling the insert method, much like a man-in-the-middle strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You must only set the `_id` attribute for documents you newly insert.

for general reference, see:
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#why-does-pymongo-add-an-id-field-to-all-of-my-documents